# Cannot unserialize Wordpress serialized values in `wp_options` table?

Tags: database, options

I have `nav_menu_options` in my Wordpress database as below.

```
284,'nav_menu_options','a:2:{i:0;b:0;s:8:\"auto_add\";a:0:{}}'
```

I tried to deserialize this value but the result is empty string - I put a code snippet in `<my theme>/function.php` as below

```
echo 'TRY #1'.'<br>';
$v = 'a:2:{i:0;b:0;s:8:\"auto_add\";a:0:{}}';
$d = unserialize($v);
print_r($d);
echo 'TRY #1 end'.'<br>';

echo 'TRY #2'.'<br>';
$v ='a:5:{s:9:"engine_id";a:1:{i:0;s:9:"300000225";}s:15:"transmission_id";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"257691";}s:5:"plant";a:1:{i:0;s:23:"Oshawa, Ontario, Canada";}s:15:"Manufactured in";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"CANADA";}s:22:"Production Seq. Number";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"151411";}}';
$d = unserialize($v);
print_r($d);
echo 'TRY #2 end'.'<br>';
```

The outcome of the above code is as below.

@1 the deserialized Worpdress value results as empty.

@2 a sample valid serialized value results as readable array.

[image]

So my question is **Why can't we deserialize Wordpress serialized values?** - this is also posted on wordpress.org [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-unserialize-wordpress-serialized-values-in-wp_options-table?replies=1#post-7225968).

p.s.

1) More study on Wordpress code shows that we can "decode" the discussed value by using `get_option('nav_menu_options');` command.

2) The value of `nav_menu_options` is the real data copied from database

[image]

Comment: What was the real data for the `nav_menu_options` field? Perhaps, problem is there. Better [edit] your question and add the real data first to prove that, your real data is serialized correctly so the unserialization should work accordingly.

Comment: I put in the real data for `nav_menu_options` already @Mayeenul Islam. Updated on my OP.

Comment: :) It's not the real data. It's already serialized. What's the real data, that's serialized into this: `a:2:{i:0;b:0;s:8:\"auto_add\";a:0:{}}`?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Well, Wordpress do the serialization for the data so I have no idea why we need to prove the real data is correct!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that serialized strings contains escape slashes that are not evaluated as such, because the *wrapping* quote is a single quote.

You are using:

```
$v = 'a:2:{i:0;b:0;s:8:\"auto_add\";a:0:{}}'; // wrong
```

You have to use  either

```
$v = "a:2:{i:0;b:0;s:8:\"auto_add\";a:0:{}}"; // ok
```

or

```
$v = 'a:2:{i:0;b:0;s:8:"auto_add";a:0:{}}'; // ok
```

By the way, you should never *manually* unserialize values in WordPress database.

When you need to get an option (or a metadata, or anything that may be serialized) use WP functions: they unserialize the value when needed.

E.g. for options, use [`get_option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/).

If you are interested in how WordPress do unserialization see [`maybe_unserialize`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/)
 and [`is_serialized`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_serialized/).

Comment: "By the way, you should never manually unserialize values in WordPress database"
---
I've had to unserialize frequently to access the inside of a user's value. Like, a plugin may store all the page visits of a user in an array within a usermeta. The only way i know how to loop through that data is through manually unserialize the value.

Comment: @RockyKev unserialize values is ok. You can use `maybe_unserialize` to obtain the unserialized value... when I say "maually" I mean messing with the string directly

Comment: @gmazzap I have tried everything to unserialize the meta doesn't work :'( somehow get_post_meta with the single=true is working but that results in huge amount of query ! which I can't waste is there another solution ! note I tried maybe_unserialize returned the same meta value as string !

Answer (score 0):

Its a very old issue but I recently faced similar issue. I was using the multi image upload plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-image-upload/ and I had Godaddy backups setup. I recently needed to restore my website from godaddy using its backup. and all of a sudden the serialized images data that multi image upload stored in post meta, the unserialize wasn't working on that.
After banging my head around it for almost 2 days, I found that instead of using the "Restore" function to restore db, i needed to downloaded the sql backup, and through phpmyadmin import it and all went well.
Seems like the restore function was corrupting the serialized data.
May help someone.